# Spring MVC database connection

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I have to create a connection with database to insert certain values in Spring MVC but there is following error in my servlet-context.xml while creating the connection:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line: - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean] - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'. - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean] Offending resource: file [E:/General Workspace/Spring Workspace/Record_mvc/ src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
```

I have declared bean with `id="dataSource"` but it seems to be not working. Could you help me to understand why it cannot find declaration for element `'bean'` and what does it mean

> "the matching wildcard is strict"

Here is the code for dispatcher. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lead.mvc" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/leadmanager" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="jdbcTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean> -->
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: please provide more code. There could be a problem with "dataSource"

Comment: There is error at line of bean id=dataSource.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean]
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
 - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean] Offending resource: file [E:/General Workspace/Spring Workspace/Record_mvc/
  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]

Comment: Check <beans:bean id="dataSource" ...  </beans:bean>. Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem is that you didn't specify wildcard for bean, so you should write:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/leadmanager" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>
```

And then is should work.

Comment: Thanks m.aibin the error is gone now. May i know what was the problem and if you know any good portal for Spring MVC than to suggest me because i have been through spring.io docs but the error didnt clicked to me.

Comment: Basics: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/ - but be careful, some of the answers are pretty old. Than google and spring.io ;) Please check the box for correct answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Again I have learned parsing from Mkyong tutorial, also i have been through spring.io as well.